# SDL2 program stops responding after a while

Tags: c, windows, gcc, sdl-2

So I am trying to do a simple sprite animation.
I am using this image as the sprite: http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/5358-1123_01_01.jpg

This is the code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;


#define PATH_TO_IMAGE "sprite.jpg"

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

    const int WALKING_ANIMATION_FRAMES = 8;

    SDL_Rect gSpriteClips[ 8 ] = {
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 16, .y = 16},
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 133, .y = 16},
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 265, .y = 16},
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 398, .y = 16},
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 16, .y = 139},
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 132, .y = 139},
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 264, .y = 139},
        (SDL_Rect) {.h = 112, .w = 88, .x = 397, .y = 139},
    };

    //The window renderer
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;

    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window *gWindow;

    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0) {
        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Character animation", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

        if (gWindow != NULL) {
            //Get window surface
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
            int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_JPG;

            if (IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags) {
                bool quit = false;


                SDL_Texture *texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, PATH_TO_IMAGE);
                int frame = 0;
                int selected_frame = 0;

                while (!quit) {         

                    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

                    selected_frame = (frame / WALKING_ANIMATION_FRAMES);

                    SDL_Rect *currentClip = &gSpriteClips[selected_frame];
                    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, currentClip, &((SDL_Rect){ .x = 16, .y = 16, .h = 112, .w = 88}) );
                    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

                    printf("Selected frame: %d -- %d - %d\n", selected_frame, frame, WALKING_ANIMATION_FRAMES);

                    ++frame;
                    if ((frame / WALKING_ANIMATION_FRAMES) >= WALKING_ANIMATION_FRAMES) {
                        printf("Entrei aqui\n");
                        frame = 0;                        
                    }
                }
            }


        } else {
            printf("SDL_Init failed ON WINDOW: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The code compiles without any issue.
This was based on Lazy Foo lesson 14.

The problem I am having is that after a 10 or 15 secs the program stops responding (the window greys out the the sprite animation stops).
Let me be clear, the animation does work and it works a few times before the program freezes (I see it cycling at least 3 or 4 times).

I have a debug printf which works and keeps on working even after the window of the program stops responding.

I initially thought I might be going over the gSpriteClips but in the printf I always see numbers equal or below 7.

Does anyone see any obvious problems I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main loop doesn't flush the SDL event queue. Copy-pasted from an SDL tutorial:

```
while( !quit ){
    // optionally your code comes here...

    // The following inner loop flushes the event queue.
    // (All events that have been queued up between two frames.)

    // declare an event struct somewhere
    SDL_Event event;

    /* Poll for events */
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ){   
        switch( event.type ){
            /* Keyboard event */
            /* Pass the event data onto PrintKeyInfo() */
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                PrintKeyInfo( &event.key );
                break;

            /* SDL_QUIT event (window close) */
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = 1;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // optionally your code comes here...
}
```

The SDL event loop is basically the equivalent of the windows `GetMessage()` loop of a typical native windows GUI application. Not consuming the messages in a GUI application on windows usually results in the greyed and stuck window symptom.

Comment: Wow. Didn't realize how important the pollevent thing was. Thanks